# Saving Array of JSON to mysql using JQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, ajax

I am sending a json array to my controller to save it to the database, the json array looks like this

```
var events = [{
"title": "English Lesson Schedule",
"start": "2017-09-17 06:30 AM",
"end": "2017-09-17 09:00 AM",
"date": "2017-09-17",
"student": "1",
"teacher": "2",
"id": 1
}, {
"title": "English Lesson Schedule",
"start": "2017-09-18 09:00 AM",
"end": "2017-09-18 10:30 AM",
"date": "2017-09-18",
"student": "1",
"teacher": "2",
"id": 2
}]
```

here's how I am sending it via JQuery AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: pp_return_url,
    data: {
        _token:token,
        "eventsArray": JSON.stringify(events)                   
     },
     success: function(response) {
         console.log(response)
     }
});
```

and here's how I process it on my controller

```
 public function payPalTest(Request $request){
    $events = json_decode($request['eventsArray']);

        foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
            $sched[$key] = new Schedule();
            $sched[$key]->student = $event[$key]['student'];
            $sched[$key]->teacher = $event[$key]['teacher'];
            $sched[$key]->lesson_name = $event[$key]['title'];
            $sched[$key]->lesson_date = $event[$key]['date'];
            $sched[$key]->time_start = $event[$key]['start'];
            $sched[$key]->time_end = $event[$key]['end'];
            $sched[$key]->save();
        }
        return response('SUCCESS'); 
}
```

My problem is that I am getting an `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error response from my controller. Any ideas what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: doing a JSON.stringify converted the json to string.. pass the json directly and see if you get the data in php

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found my error already.

I didn't notice I was trying to get the values from the individual object inside the array so instead of

```
 foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
        $sched[$key] = new Schedule();
        $sched[$key]->student = $event[$key]['student'];
        $sched[$key]->teacher = $event[$key]['teacher'];
        $sched[$key]->lesson_name = $event[$key]['title'];
        $sched[$key]->lesson_date = $event[$key]['date'];
        $sched[$key]->time_start = $event[$key]['start'];
        $sched[$key]->time_end = $event[$key]['end'];
        $sched[$key]->save();
    }
```

I fixed it by changing the variable `$event` to `$events` since `$events` is the collection and I am looping through it and getting the values by index so I did this

```
foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
        $sched[$key] = new Schedule();
        $sched[$key]->student = $events[$key]['student'];
        $sched[$key]->teacher = $events[$key]['teacher'];
        $sched[$key]->lesson_name = $events[$key]['title'];
        $sched[$key]->lesson_date = $events[$key]['date'];
        $sched[$key]->time_start = $events[$key]['start'];
        $sched[$key]->time_end = $events[$key]['end'];
        $sched[$key]->save();
    }
```

Now it's working and I am able to save it in my database